# AngularJS + Rails: Unknown provider: e

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

After moving to production server using Rails 4 and AngularJS, I came across error: `[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module EcoApp due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: e`.
After reading other stackoverflow questions and angular docs, I suppose the error appears because of minification. Unfortunately, I don't know angular good enough and after several attempts to fix my code, I decided to search for help here.

My controller file (in CoffeeScript):

```
angular.module('EcoApp')
.controller 'MyTripsCtrl', ($scope, $http) ->

  $http.get('/mytrips.json').success((data, status, headers, config) ->

    $scope.mytrips = data

    return

  ).error (data, status, headers, config) ->

    # log error

    return

  return


.controller 'NavbarIsActive', ($scope, $location) ->

  $scope.isActive = (select_path) ->

    select_path == $location.path()



  return


.controller 'NavbarIsActive2', [

  '$scope'

  '$location'

  ($scope, $location) ->

    $scope.isActive = (select_path) ->

      select_path == $location.path()

    return
]
```

As you can see, I tried to fix controller NavbarIsActive, which in my opinion is cause of trouble, but with no results. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is something minifying your code? I see no reference to `e` in any of the controllers that you've included. If you are, in fact, minifying your code, you need to use the explicit dependency format rather than allowing Angular to infer your dependencies by name.

Comment: I suppose that Rails is minifying my code after changing server from development to production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the problem is likely minification. If a minifier garbles your code into this:

```
.controller('Foobar', function (e) { .. })
```

then Angular doesn't have any information about what exactly it needs to inject. That's why the alternative injection syntax exists, which you need to use everywhere:

```
.controller 'Foobar', ['$scope', '$location', ($scope, $location) ->
    ..
]
```

You specify each dependency twice: once as a string, which will not get minified, and the second time as an arbitrary variable name in your actual function signature.